# If we have two invertible $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with $BA=A^2B$, then how to show that one of the given conditions hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a problem from a qualifying exam I just took.

> It is given that $A$ and $B$ are invertible $2\times 2$ matrices with $BA=A^2B$. I need to show that either $A^3=I$ or $A$ is not diagonalizable, but $B$ is.

I could not solve this problem. What I did was to observe that $A$ and $A^2$ are similar and so if eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, then $(\lambda_1^2,\lambda_2^2)$ is a permutation of $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$. The only possibilities on computation are that both are 1 or they are the two complex cube roots of unity. If both are 1 and minimal polynomial is $A-I$ then $A^3=I$ holds. If the eigenvalues are complex cube roots of unity, then $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix with the two cube roots on the diagonal. In this case also, it's easy to check that $A^3=I$ holds. If not, then $A$ is similar to the matrix in Jordan form, with 1s on the diagonal and a 1 above the diagonal. In this case, clearly $A$ is not diagonalizable. Up to this, I went smoothly. But how do I show that in this last case, $B$ will be diagonalizable?

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If $ A $ is similar to

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

then we may, without loss of generality, assume that $ A $ is in fact equal to this matrix, by conjugating both sides of the equality by some invertible matrix if necessary. Then, writing out the condition on $ B $ gives

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x & x+y \\ z & z+t \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x + 2z & y + 2t \\ z & t \end{bmatrix} $$

It follows immediately that $ z = 0 $ and $ x = 2t $, so that this matrix is of the form

$$ B =  \begin{bmatrix} 2t & y + 2t \\ 0 & t \end{bmatrix} $$

Moreover, we know that $ B $ is invertible, which implies that $ t \neq 0 $, so that $ 2t \neq t $. Therefore, $ B $ has distinct eigenvalues, and is therefore diagonalizable.